# Python Function does not return True

Tags: python

pretty new to python and trying out some small exercices.
Im stuck at a funciton which does not return true:

```
def pay(ch):
    price = MENU[ch]["cost"]
    quarters = int(input("How many quarters?")) * 0.25
    dimes = int(input("How many dimes?")) * 0.10
    nickles = int(input("How many nickles?")) * 0.05
    pennies = int(input("How many pennies?")) * 0.01
    budget = quarters + dimes + nickles + pennies
    global money
    if budget >= price:
        money += price
        print(f"Your change: {round((budget - price),2)} ")
        return True
    else:
        print("Not enough money")
        return False
```

I printed it out, if budget is higher than price, balance does gett added to money, and the print also executes, but it does not return True.
Here im calling the function:

```
if enough(choice)== True:
    pay(choice)
    print(pay(choice))
    if pay(choice) == True:
        make_coffee(choice)
    else:
        print("Nope")
```

I really dont understand why it does not return True, but executes the print statement.
Same goes for else, print statement executes, but no return False

Comment: FYI, if `x` is a boolean expression then writing `if x == True:` is functionally identical to `if x:`, and makes no sense. Remove the `== True` part.

Comment: Like a true salesman, you like to make them pay(choice) three times :) but only the third time you check if they can pay (==True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are paying (=calling `pay` function) more than once!

You should call the function once and save the result in a variable: then you can do whatever you want with it

```
result = pay(choice)
# print(result)
if result:
    make_coffee(choice)
else:
    print("Nope")
```

Comment: Thank you, saving it to a variale fixed the problem. Why did it cause a problem calling the functiion more than once? should have been true every time?

Comment: Every function call, the `money` variable will be changed! On the second (and third) call, you don't have the same money as the first time. It's like you are "paying" multiple times. Is it clear now? @Retr0

Comment: Ah yea true, i didnt even come to notice that user gets charged too much. But apart from money var not correct, shouldnt the function return True every time? Cause every time i call it, the budget will be higher than price, so True should be returned? Cause as noticed the print statement gets triggerd